# Java Fluent Math API conventions

Tags: java, coding-style, fluent, api-design, calling-convention

I'm currently making small Math api for Quaternions, Matrices, ... and I came accross, while developing the methods with the question, how to design them properly for fluent usage.

Given this example ...

```
public class Quaternion {
  private double q0,q1,q2,q3;

  public Quaternion slerp(Quaternion other, float amt){         
    // Some calculations

    // First option return this and update the object
    return this;    

    // Second option - Create a new Instance
    return new Quaternion(res.getQ0(), res.getQ1(), res.getQ2(), res.getQ3());
  }
```

> ... there are two possibilities of returning the result. First with the updated instance or a completly new one.

Is there any convention how to design such method which intended to be fluently used wich other functions (multipy, rotate, conjugate) ?

For example Java BigDecimal, BigInteger classes are designed to return a new Object instead of returning the actual instance.

On the other side some libaries are using the **return this** approach.

From my side I find ...

```
Quaternion result = start.slerp(other, 0.25f); // return new object
```

... more reasonable than this

```
start.slerp(other, 0.25f); // return this
```

Imagine with the second approach you want to make another calculation below with the original [start] object. then you would need to create a temp variable before the slerp method.

Is there any experience with this from your side ? Is one of these approaches (eg. new for immutabel, return this for mutable) more commonly used ,or is this just a question of deciding for one approach and than stick with it in the hole API ?

Comment: Do you want your objects to be immutable, like `BigDecimal`, or do you want them to be more of the builder pattern, like `StringBuilder`, where you continually modify the state of the object? Either way is *fluent*. I don't believe the choice between the two has anything to do with fluent.